# Install Nokia .sis applications from Mac OS X

Tags: macos

I have got a bunch of applications and packages as .sis files which I would like to install on my Nokia S60 device. How do I do this from a Mac? Nokia does not have a "PC Suite" program for Mac OS X, and I cannot find out how to open a .sis file once transfered to the device using USB.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just transfer the SIS files over with USB, Bluetooth, Device Browser of [Nokia Multimedia Transfer](http://europe.nokia.com/get-support-and-software/download-software/nokia-multimedia-transfer) or whatever.

You can use the built-in file manager (under Office) to browse for the SIS file and open it, or you can use a third party file browser like [Y-Browser](http://www.drjukka.com/YBrowser.html).

Virtual machine solutions with PC Suite work too but are probably an overkill for this purpose.

Answer (score 2):

I've heard good things about [The Missing Sync](http://www.markspace.com/products/symbian/ms-overview-mac.php) for general, but I have not used it myself.  It doesn't appear to support application installation because of code signing requirements, but I may be wrong.  You would probably be best off installing Windows inside something like [VirtualBox](http://www.virtualbox.org/) or [VMware Fusion](http://www.vmware.com/products/fusion/) to use the Windows desktop software for installing applications, and then using The Missing Sync for your day-to-day stuff.

> Device Requirements
>
> The Missing Sync for Nokia (built on
>   the powerful Missing Sync for Symbian
>   sync engine) is compatible with most
>   Nokia mobile phones, devices and
>   handsets running Symbian S60 (3rd Rev
>   or later) and Sony Ericsson and
>   Motorola mobile phones running Symbian
>   UIQ 3.0 or later.

Comment: I used the Windows Mobile version and it works very well.

Comment: Is there a free trial available? I don't feel like buy an application that does not do what I want it to...

Comment: It doesn't look like a free trail is available, unfortunately.