# Installation sis file on my Mac

Tags: macos

Duplicate Question:
[Install Nokia sis application from Mac OS X](https://superuser.com/questions/34808/install-nokia-sis-applications-from-os-x)

---

How can I install some sis files through macbook?
The Nokia PC suite isnt supported on Mac...

Answer (score 1):

Mac isn't an acronym.

Now, check out [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/34808/install-nokia-sis-applications-from-os-x).

Answer (score 0):

Run Windows in a virtual machine under VMware Fusion or VirtualBox